# Using "on" for response for desired elements only:

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

[***JS Fiddle Link***](http://jsfiddle.net/hbac7vbh/)

I am dynamically adding some elements and my `div` looks like:

```
<div class="knock" href="#">  
    <!-- Do Something if links are not clicked -->
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

And my `on` script is:

```
$(".knock").on("click", function(){
 console.log("Link not clicked");   
 alert("Link not Clicked");   

});
```

My Problem, I do not want to fire the alert when the links are clicked. Is there a way out?

Comment: What else could be clicked in the div that triggers the handler but is not a link?

Comment: Maybe try event delegation: `$(".knock").on("click", ":not(a)", function(e){…})`

Comment: @Bergi some `span` elements

Comment: Please add them to your markup so that it gets clear. What should happen when the div itself is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write anchor tag event and stop event Propagation of the event to upper DOM elements so that alert only comes up when the div is actually clicked, but not when some anchor tag inside div is clicked:

```
$(".knock").on('click',"a",function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

})
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/hbac7vbh/2/

### event.stopPropagation:

> > The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

See [**details here on jquery official page**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: +1 This solution works even if the `a` element has other elements within it http://jsfiddle.net/hbac7vbh/13/

Answer (score 2):

Just determine if the `a` is clicked based on the event that is passed.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8myznL3/)

```
$(".knock").on("click", function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('a')){
        console.log("Link not clicked");
        alert("Link not Clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, even if that might not work if the links contain other elements

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your js:

```
$(".knock a").on("click", function(e) {
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I need to redirect the Links. Just avoid the alerts

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another method as

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop porpagation of the chaininvocation of events on parent elements.

See updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbac7vbh/7/)

Comment: Elements are added dynamically.

Comment: So while adding the elements you can set its `onclick()` property to this. or use `on()` @Bergi